# If the group of automorfisms of E/F fixes exactly F, is the extension Galois?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I'm reading the [wikipedia article on Galois extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension).

Something confuses me a  bit:

A result by Artin is mentioned: if G is a finite group of automorfisms of F and the field fixed by G is E then F/E is a Galois extension. Later in the examples part (first bullet) they seem to be implying finiteness of G is not needed or am I simply reading the claim wrong?

Comment: I think the wiki page assumed finiteness in the examples part. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory#Infinite_case for the one-sentence introduction to the infinite Galois theory. And Chapter 7 of J.Milne's notes for Fields and Galois Theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is an infinite group of automorphisms of the field $F$ with  fixed field $E=F^G$, the extension $F/E$ has no reason to be algebraic, let alone Galois.
For example the rational function field  $F=\mathbb C(T)$ admits for every $n\in \mathbb Z$ of a unique field automorphism $g_n:\mathbb C(T) \to \mathbb C(T)$ fixing $\mathbb C$ and satisfying $g_n (T)=T+n$.
The group $G=\{g_n\vert n\in \mathbb Z\}$ of these automorphisms has as fixed field $F^G= E=\mathbb C$ and the purely transcendental extension $E=\mathbb C \subset F=\mathbb C(T)$ is thus definitely not algebraic.